# Call function after a period of time in C#

Tags: c#

I have a c# code with call function something like:

```
private void cmdCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       m_socClient.Close();
    }
```

But now i want the `m_socClient.Close();` function to be called after maybe 30 second. So is that possible?

Comment: You mean 30 seconds after the click?  Or 30 seconds after the dialog has been opened (automatic dismissal)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 30 seconds after click,however answer has been solved. Tq for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using [`async / await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature:

```
private async void cmdCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    await Task.Delay(30000);
    m_socClient.Close();
}
```

You can also do that using `Thread.Sleep` but it will block your `UI` thread and your window won't be responsive until the task is finished.